# ng-repeat shows objects but not elements of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show specific elements from objects I receive from a service using ng-repeat. When I use {{account}} it renders all the elements, but when I try for example {{account.idType}} it shows nothing. What's going on?
Here is my HTML

```
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>List of Accounts</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="account in accounts"  ng-if="account.idType != 0">
          <tr>
            <td>{{account.idType}}</td>
            <td>{{account.linkRel}}</td>
            <td>{{account.linkURI}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" ng-click="editAccount(account.idType)" value="edit"></td>
         </div>
```

and this is the controller:

```
rest.controller('accountListCtrl',['$scope','$resource','$location','$parse','$routeParams',
    function($scope,$resource, $location, $parse,$routeParams)
    {   
      var Account = $resource('http://localhost\\:8085/WSAT/account/');
       $scope.accounts = Account.get();
    }]);
```

the response I get from the service is this:

```
{"linklist":[{"idType":"0","linkRel":"Get all accounts","linkType":"Sibling","linkURI":"http://localhost:8085/WSAT/account","linkVerb":"GET"},{"idType":"0","linkRel":"Create a new account","linkType":"Sibling","linkURI":"http://localhost:8085/WSAT/account","linkVerb":"POST"},{"idType":"7","linkRel":"try","linkType":"Child","linkURI":"http://localhost:8085/WSAT/account/7","linkVerb":"GET"},{"idType":"9","linkRel":"try234","linkType":"Child","linkURI":"http://localhost:8085/WSAT/account/9","linkVerb":"GET"}]}
```

Comment: Can you show your response object from the endpoint?  Hard to troubleshoot without seeing what's returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$resource` is asynchronous (It returns a promise).
Replace `$scope.accounts = Account.get()` by

```
Account.get().then(function(data){
 $scope.accounts=data.result;
});
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me. I get an error that Account.get() is not a function. maybe it needs another syntax?

Comment: Sorry, replace just in your original code ng-repeat="account in accounts" by : ng-repeat="account in accounts.linklist"